# AWS SSM-Agent not starting

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

When I try to deploy Cloudformation template by using AWS standard script template for RHEL7 [from github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/solutions/HelperNonAmaznAmi/RHEL7_cfn-hup.template) I receive error :
Error occurred during build: Could not enable service amazon-ssm-agent (return code 1)

Answer (score 0):

already solved the issue, the solution was installing the polkit in userdata, before the calling cfn-init `yum install polkit`